# Get all the records which has two most highest values for a specific field - MySQL

Tags: mysql, limit

I want to add restrictions on the result like, only those records should appear in the result which has two most highest value for *votes* field.

**Query:**

```
SELECT  `dev`.`user_id` ,  `dev`.`fullname` , COUNT(  `pom_votes`.`performer_id` ) AS votes
FROM  `pom_votes` 
INNER JOIN  `dev` ON  `pom_votes`.`performer_id` =  `dev`.`user_id` 
WHERE MONTH( pom_votes.created_at ) =1
AND YEAR( pom_votes.created_at ) =2017
GROUP BY  `performer_id` 
ORDER BY  `votes` DESC ,  `id` DESC
```

**Output:**

```
user_id | fullname | votes
--------------------------
53      | test1    |  3  |
60      | test2    |  2  |
57      | test3    |  2  |
55      | test4    |  2  |
52      | test5    |  2  |
51      | test6    |  2  |
75      | test7    |  1  |
83      | test8    |  1  |
61      | test9    |  1  |
58      | test10   |  1  |
```

**Needed output:**

```
user_id | fullname | votes
--------------------------
53      | test1    |  3  |
60      | test2    |  2  |
57      | test3    |  2  |
55      | test4    |  2  |
52      | test5    |  2  |
51      | test6    |  2  |
```

**Explanation:**

See in the needed output, I want all the records which has most two highest values for **votes** field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this two separate queries:

**Queries 1:**

```
select DISTINCT count(`pom_votes`.`performer_id`) as votes from `pom_votes` where MONTH(pom_votes.created_at) = 1 and YEAR(pom_votes.created_at) = 2017 group by `performer_id` order by `votes` desc, `id` desc LIMIT 2
```

**Queries 2:**

```
select `dev`.`user_id`, `dev`.`fullname`, count(`pom_votes`.`performer_id`) as votes from `pom_votes` inner join `dev` on `pom_votes`.`performer_id` = `dev`.`user_id` where MONTH(pom_votes.created_at) = 1 and YEAR(pom_votes.created_at) = 2017 group by `performer_id` having votes in(RESULT OF QUERY 1) order by `votes` desc, `id` desc
```

Might not be the perfect solution, but it works.